# How can I programmatically center UITextview across all devices?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

My current code is below

```
    class SetupScene: SKScene{
        let myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 208, y: 175, width: 230.00, height: 33.00));

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pixelBackground")
        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        background.size = self.size
        background.zPosition = -10
        self.addChild(background)

        self.view?.addSubview(myTextField)

        myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        myTextField.text = "Enter your name:"
        myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
        myTextField.textAlignment = .center
        myTextField.font = UIFont(name: "04b_25", size: 25)

    }
}
```

With the code above myTextField is at the top left of my screen(my screens in landscape orientation). I can manually move it where I want by inputing numbers into the x and y values but then it moves to different places depending on the device. And when I try to do:

```
    myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2, width: 230.00, height: 33.00))
```

myTextField is missing from the screen. How can I center across all devices like I would in SpriteKit with: (x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)

*Note I want to do this programmatically not with Storyboards

Answer (score 1):

Don't use frames. Use AutoLayout.

Set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the view (text field) to false, and then use an X axis `NSLayoutAnchor` and a Y axis `NSLayoutAnchor` to make the center of your view be equal to the center of it's superview.

Comment: I accidentally uploaded code after a few edits where it wouldn't show up. Now I edited the code to show what it looks like when its at the top left. With the updated code should I still use NSLayout Anchor?

Comment: @ItsSgtMarv You can use `myTextField.center = self.center` if you don't want to use  `NSLayoutAnchor`..

Comment: @Daniel, that solution is fragile. If you manipulate a view's frame or center, the AutoLayout system is likely to override your view positioning based on it's guess as to where the view should be positioned.

Comment: @ItsSgtMarv, yes you should still use NSLayoutAnchor

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Custom class** and use it as globally where you need.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }
     func setUp() {
    //Setting constraints of CustomTextField with centerX, centerY
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.superview?.centerYAnchor)!).isActive = true
    self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.superview?.centerXAnchor)!).isActive = true
    //use if you want fixed width
    self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    //self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    self.backgroundColor = .red
    self.textAlignment = .center
}
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var demoText = CustomTextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(demoText)
        demoText.setUp()
        demoText.text = "hello"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Custom classing would just add to the hassle,  I would recommend just creating an extension for your setup function to keep it simplistic